# Using lapply to set column names for a list of data frames?

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I'm pretty new to R but I'm trying to create a list of data frames and then give them all the same headers in a loop. The plan is to then fill the columns with data from a bunch of messy data files and then bind the small data frames all a single data frame. However, I'm stuck on assigning the column names. I did first try a for loop but saw other answers saying that was the newbie way to do it.

This is what I have right now but when I run it the columns don't update:

```
a <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=5, nrow=1))
b <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=5, nrow=1))
c <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=5, nrow=1))
d <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=5, nrow=1))

List <- list(a, b, c, d)
headers <- c("First Name","Last Name","Date","Zip Code", "blah")

lapply(List, setNames, nm = headers)
```

I think I'm missing something about how data frames are updated in R because I do get a print out of 4 empty data frames with the right column names. So the function is applying to something! But it's not updating my list and I'm failing to understand why.

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly does not work? Your current code prints the result to the console. If you want to save the changes you‘d need to assign the result like List2 <- lapply…. Note this will also only update the list, NOT the original a, b, c, d data frames.

Comment: `List <- lapply(List, setNames, nm = headers)`

Comment: Ah so lapply is basically just making a new instance of the data frames with those headers but it's not saving back to the original. Is there a way to do that instead? A function I should check out? Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: @MarkTheRobot do you want to update the dataframes or the List?

Comment: That is a great question, I think that's where my understand gap is. I want to update the data frames but I've been thinking I could do that by putting them in a list and then updating the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to update the original dataframes. In that case, your list MUST be named. ie check the code below.

```
List <- list(a = a, b = b, c = c, d = d)
list2env(lapply(List, setNames, nm = headers), globalenv())
```

Now if you call `a` you will note that it has been updated.

Answer (score 2):

We can set column names using,

```
List = lapply(List, function(x) `colnames<-`(x, headers))
```

Comment: What is the difference between what you have and what OP has?

Comment: Its just another method.

Comment: meaning you have not answerd the question then?

Comment: It does answer.

Comment: I guess where I'm confused is how to assign those column names to the data frames and then reference them again. I'm getting now that lapply is making a new list of data frames not updating my existing ones. I tried List <- lapply(List, function(x) `colnames<-`(x, headers)) but that still doesn't update the data frames

Comment: How does it answer the question? The question was to update the original dataframes/list. Lapply creates a new list.

Comment: It's cool though, I'm learning there are actually a lot of ways to do what I've been doing, it's just not getting the results I wanted